# nginx remove header from upstream

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I have nginx with upstream.

The upstream sets headers:

```
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
```

Because I want this page to be cached, in nginx I have following conf:

```
    location ~* ^.+\.(html)$ {
            proxy_pass      http://websitefarm.php73;

            add_header      Pragma          "";
            add_header      x-pragma        "OK";
            expires         1d;
    }
```

it successfully remove Expires and Cache-Control, but Pragma stays.

note my test header "x-pragma" is set. so definitely conf "works"

```
expires: Sat, 25 Jul 2020 12:13:04 GMT
cache-control: max-age=86400
pragma: no-cache
x-pragma: OK
```

if i try set "Pragma" to something else, it works, but "" not seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this can be removed only with `proxy_hide_header` directive

Following config works:

```
    location ~* ^.+\.(html)$ {
            proxy_pass              http://websitefarm.php73;
            proxy_hide_header       Pragma;
            expires                 1d;
    }
```

Comment: This works fine with Nginx + Jenkins setup

Answer (score 2):

This is a PHP configuration issue. You have set [`session.cache_limiter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cache-limiter) to `nocache`, either by leaving it at its default or by setting it explicitly in code, or both.

If the pages of interest are indeed cacheable, and are not for logged-in users, you need to have a chat with the application's developer about the inappropriate use of sessions.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you. I found how to remove it, but now I know where header come from.